# Possible to set default sort to "Type" in File Explorer using script?

Tags: windows-explorer, powershell, script, sorting

Is there any way to automatically sort all files in Windows by TYPE as opposed to NAME?

Generally this is done by going to a folder, sorting by type, then going to the Ribbon, View, Options, View, then clicking Apply to Folders, then OK.

[image]

That's a lot of work to change just one setting.

Furthermore, I am using a PC where the user profile is wiped after restart, so I don't want to do this every time I login. I've already written a PowerShell script to do the other customizations that I need. Is there any Registry setting or something of the like that can be modified using a script so this doesn't have to be done manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you ask if there are any methods that can do this with a script rather than needing to be done manually, I've included a batch script and a VB script that you can use either to set those settings that you would have to do otherwise using [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html) to emulate the pressing of the **File Explorer** keyboard Alt shortcut keys plus some other emulated keyboard key strokes and such.

---

### Batch Script

```
IF NOT DEFINED MINIMIZED SET MINIMIZED=1 && START "" /MIN "%~dpnx0" %* && EXIT
@ECHO OFF

SET TempVBSFile=%temp%\~tmpSendKeysTemp.vbs
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"

ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 900                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "%%vyo"                            >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 1500                                   >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 9}{RIGHT}{TAB}{ENTER}"       >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"                         >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"

EXIT /B
```

---

### VB Script

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Wscript.Sleep 900                                    
WshShell.SendKeys "%vyo"                             
Wscript.Sleep 1500                                   
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB 9}{RIGHT}{TAB}{ENTER}"       
Wscript.Sleep 500                                    
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          
Wscript.Sleep 500                                    
WshShell.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
```

---

> ### Instructions
>
> 1. Navigate to a folder with **File Explorer** and then sort by the applicable column which you want to apply to all folders via **File
>      Explorer**.
> 2. Copy either the VBS or the batch script to this folder and then simple double click to execute either and the rest will be fully
>      automated from there.
> 3. Essentially it'll press <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>,<kbd>`V`</kbd>,<kbd>`Y`</kbd>,<kbd>`O`</kbd>, wait
>      for 1.5 seconds, then press <kbd>`Tab`</kbd> 9
>      times,<kbd>**`→`**</kbd>`Tab`<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>, wait half a second
>      then press <kbd>`Enter`</kbd>, wait half a second and finally press
>      <kbd>`Esc`</kbd> to close the **Folder Options** window.
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]
>
>    [image]

---

### Further Resources

- [sendkeys](http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html)
- [cscript](http://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html)